# About using Mesh Topology geometry nodes to make a selection

Tags: geometry-nodes

I tried to use the Mesh Topology nodes to select a specific edge of a face. So far, the results are good, but I can only select one face at a time - I use the *Integer* value to do that.

Now, I would like to know how to use all the faces index (or a certain range) at the same time. Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: 3.4 it's still in beta, so there are some bugs to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you trying to achieve?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank you! This tweak is pretty odd, but it works fine!

Comment: Ah! You don't need the Sample node, it seems...

Comment: you are right, i updated my answer